# VNC Server failling to start at boot

Tags: vnc

I have installed VNC Server, it starts from the command line and I am able to connect from my laptop. The problem is that I can not make start up at boot, which forces me to link a monitor, keyboard and mouse to the Raspberry each time I switch it on.

I have the following script at `/etc/init.d`:

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/vncboot

USER=root
HOME=/root

export USER HOME

case "$1" in
 start)
   echo "Starting VNC Server"
   #Insert your favoured settings for a VNC session
   /usr/bin/vncserver :2 -geometry 1680x945 -depth 24
   ;;

 stop)
   echo "Stopping VNC Server"
   /usr/bin/vncserver -kill :0
   ;;

 *)
   echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/vncboot {start|stop}"
   exit 1
   ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any way to understand what is failing?

Comment: This looks OK.
Have you set permissions to 755? See http://elinux.org/RPi_VNC_Server#Run_at_boot You don't need to use a monitor, keyboard and mouse. When I want to run `tightvncserver` I `ssh` into my Pi and start it from there.

Answer (score 2):

*The following process worked for me, it's a little long but I hope it helps:*

Log into a terminal on the Pi as root:

```
sudo su
```

Navigate to the directory /etc/init.d/:

```
cd /etc/init.d/
```

Create a new file here containing the following script:

```bash
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/vncboot

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: vncboot
# Required-Start: $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start VNC Server at boot time
# Description: Start VNC Server at boot time.
### END INIT INFO

USER=pi
HOME=/home/pi

export USER HOME

case "$1" in
 start)
  echo "Starting VNC Server"
  #Insert your favoured settings for a VNC session
  su - $USER -c "/usr/bin/vncserver :1 -geometry 1280x800 -depth 16 -pixelformat rgb565"
  ;;

 stop)
  echo "Stopping VNC Server"
  /usr/bin/vncserver -kill :1
  ;;

 *)
  echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/vncboot {start|stop}"
  exit 1
  ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Save this file as vncboot (for example)

Make this file executable:

```
chmod 755 vncboot
```

Enable dependency-based boot sequencing:

```
update-rc.d lightdm remove
update-rc.d vncboot defaults
```

If enabling dependency-based boot sequencing was successful, you will see this:

```
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
```

Reboot your Raspberry Pi and you should find a VNC server already started.